# Getting error unexpected status: SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE -- backing Kafka cluster has not completed booting try again later

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have created HLF on aws eks. I am trying to implement kakfa based orderer with 3 orderer, When I am implement it. its giving error like

```
"Error: got unexpected status: SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE -- backing Kafka cluster has not completed booting; try again later
"
```

I checked the orderer logs its still giving same error in one orderer and two remain same. Please see attached screenshot of orderer logs.

[image: orderer logs]

Comment: I suggest to avoid using Kafka, the support is going to be deprecated, just move to Raft.

Comment: Thanks I am using now the raft only however still getting some issue with it

Comment: Please state your Fabric version, your Kafka version, and if you use TLS to connect to the Kafka brokers

Comment: Hi @Paul, Thanks for the help, now I am trying to implement Raft orderer. Still getting some issue with it also.